# Is ShaderModel 3.0 supported on an ATi Radeon x1200?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a ATI Radeon X1200 (AMD) and i am trying to play COD MW2.

When i try to play, it gives the following error message:

> Video card or driver doesn't support
>   vertex shader 3.0 or better.

Now, is this in my case a card or a driver problem?
If a driver problem, can someone give me a download link to an update?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card [doesn't support](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Radeon-Xpress-X1200.3775.0.html) ShaderModel 3.0. Only way is a hardware upgrade.

Citations & Additional details

1. While for the AMD 690G chipset, the IGP is named "Radeon X1250", as for AMD 690V chipset, the **IGP is clocked lower and having fewer functions and thus named "Radeon X1200"** - [Reference 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#Product_naming_scheme)
2. Chipset models in the series (excluding RD690 and RX690) feature an Integrated Graphics Processor (IGP) [...] **based on Radeon R420 and contains 4 pixel pipelines capable of Shader Model version 2.0b with DirectX 9 and OpenGL 2.0 compatibility but lacks hardware vertex processing**- [Reference 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_690_chipset_series#IGP_General_features)
3. **For 690V, "Radeon X1200" was the name of the IGP, with clock frequency of 350MHz.** The major differences between the 690G and 690V chipsets is that the 690V chipset lacks support for TMDS output and no HDMI output, therefore limited to VGA or LVDS output only - [Reference 3](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Radeon-Xpress-X1200.3775.0.html)

Comment: The quoted source says: "Technically the chip has 4 pixel-pipelines and either a texture unit (with 2 vertex shaders) or no vertex shaders (each source tells a different story)". So this is not a conclusive answer.

Comment: @harry: Added additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first to update your video driver to the latest version (from the manufacturer's site, not thru Windows Update).

Some info regarding your O/S would be helpful.